# Having issues with glclear and GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-code, glfw

So I'm having issues with glClear and GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT not being "declared".
here are the errors

```
[build] ../src/main.cpp:27:17: error: ‘GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT’ was not declared in this scope
[build]    27 |         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
[build]       |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] ../src/main.cpp:27:9: error: ‘glClear’ was not declared in this scope
[build]    27 |         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~
```

Heres the code

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
    }

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Heres the cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(OpenGL VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(OpenGL src/main.cpp)
```

I'm using arch Linux and I'm using vs codium

Comment: Why have you defined `GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE`?  That [`"will explicitly to prevent[sic] the GLFW header from including the OpenGL header"`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.4/build.html#build_include) which is where these symbols are defined.  Try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

You told GLFW to *not* `#include` the appropriate system `gl.h` ([via `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3.1/build_guide.html#build_macros)) so you'll have to `#include` it yourself (or remove that `#define`).

Comment: I was told to do do this on their site and fixed other issues and I read a bit about it and it says it's supposed to remove any conflicts but I'll try it Edit: I've tried this and fails to include glfw and errors on glfw defined lines.

Comment: Also I defined gl.h and got the that the file or directory doesn't exist(I don't think your talking about glad but I tried including it via the directory I have it in and it didn't work.)

Comment: @MeowskiesStudia For what it's worth, I took your code, commented out the `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` directive and it compiles just fine (Linux + glfw 3.3).

Comment: @G.M. whenever I remove the #define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE it fails to include glfw and gives me debug errors that the glfw functions aren't  defined (sorry for getting to this late)